# Pandas: Create dataframe based on specific columns from another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to create the `clinical` dataframe with a `sex` column based on the `Sex` column in the `raw_clinical_patient` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_clinical_patient = pd.read_csv("./gbm_tcga/data_clinical_patient.txt", sep="\t", header=4) # Skip first 4 rows

clinical = pd.DataFrame()
clinical["sex"] = raw_clinical_patient.loc[:,"Sex"]
clinical["last_fu"] = raw_clinical_patient.loc[:,"Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"]
```

Traceback:

```
KeyError: 'Sex'
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `raw_clinical_patient` doesn't contain a column named `'Sex'`. Most likely the file header is not being read the way you think it is. What is the output of `print(raw_clinical_patient.columns)`? Also, it would help a lot if you share the first few lines of the file, so we can reproduce the same problem. Always create  a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive, so I think there probably is a `sex` column in your `raw_clinical_patient` data frame rather than a `Sex` column.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply write

```
clinical=raw_clinical_patient[["Sex","Last Alive Less Initial Pathologic Diagnosis Date Calculated Day Value"]]
clinical.columns=['sex','last_fu'] #rename accordingly
```